# Why won't Code::Blocks Build->Abort kill my running C++ program?

Tags: codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 12.11 on Windows 7.

I am writing small programs for learning and they don't appear to contain any infinite loops  but regardless, Build->Abort does not work in those situations in which I find that I have to use it for some reason after Build->Run.

In this most recent case, the following is displayed in the "Build log" tab of the "Logs & others" window at the bottom of the screen.

> Checking for existence: C:\CodeBlocks\Test_Cpp11\bin\Debug\Test_Cpp11.exe Executing:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe"
>   "C:\CodeBlocks\Test_Cpp11\bin\Debug\Test_Cpp11.exe"  (in
>   C:\CodeBlocks\Test_Cpp11.)

I exited Code::Blocks, came back in, reopened the project, and immediately ran the program and it ran fine.

EDIT: I found out the problem. If the "console window" - that came up to display cout statements - is still open, then you will have a greyed out Build->Run and Build->Build items until you close that window. My assumption that I needed to do Build->Abort at that point was incorrect. As pointed out in the answer below, that would not abort a running project process anyway, only a build/compile process that may be running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To kill the running process while you are debugging, click on the red-color 'X' button on the debug bar. This is the button named "**Stop Debugging**" in the image shown below.

[image: Code::Blocks debug toolbar]

In Code::Blocks, the Build->Abort menu item will abort building (making or compiling) your project. It has nothing to do with killing a running process. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I looked at the Debug menu and just about everything was greyed out, including "Stop Debugger". I had just done a Build->Run to run the program. Thanks for the info on Abort/Running Process.

Comment: Actually, I just found out my error as it came up again after a successful lrun. if the output Window which came up to display cout statements is till open, you can't rebuild. So once I closed that I was able to build or run again.

Comment: To debug the program, you can click on Debug >> Start or press the F8 key, which is the shortcut for start debugging. Using Build >> Run will run the program as an independent process and Code::Blocks won't have control over it.

Comment: @Scooter I think my answer is added to your question only. You can mark my answer as correct and close the question.

Comment: This is wrong. The build abort button _certainly does_ kill the running process. It's supposed to do that, and it does, too. There is however, a somewhat annoying bug (at least in my present build, might have been fixed in SVN) which causes the console runner helper process to persist, which prevents you from doing another build or rebuild afterwards. The "stop debug" button has nothing to do with it.

Comment: So how do you kill the console runner helper, without using a separate tool like task manager? If this is a bug, why is it still in C::B after 4 years?

Answer (score 6):

THis happens when the previous execution is not terminated properly.
On windows, Open up the task manager and kill the commandline processes which contain the output of the previous run. Doing so will restore the build / run to icons to green and they are rendered available.

Comment: Do you know what is the name of the commandline process to kill?

Comment: @YuDeng I **think** it can vary depending on the project/file type, but for console applications it's called *cb_console_runner.exe*

Answer (score 0):

When the application has completed and returned from its `main` function, it will prompt you to "Press any key to continue".

Once you do so, this will abort the launched process and the build buttons will no longer be greyed out.